# Flutter app suddenly ran into error [deprecation] queryIntentActivities(Intent,int) in PackageManager has been deprecated

Tags: android, flutter, dart, package

I've been running my app just fine, but today when I opened and ran my app there seems to be an error which made my app not able to run at all.
here is the error that is showing up :

```
> C:\Users\1388\development\sdks\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.3.0\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\ServiceManager.java:75:
> warning: [deprecation] queryIntentActivities(Intent,int) in
> PackageManager has been deprecated
>             List<ResolveInfo> callAppsList = pm.queryIntentActivities(callIntent, 0);
>
>                                                ^ error: warnings found and -Werror specified
> C:\Users\1388\development\sdks\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.3.0\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:317:
> warning: [deprecation] getPackageInfo(String,int) in PackageManager
> has been deprecated
>                     .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
```

[image]

Weird thing is that Im not using PackageManager, could it be that one of the packages that I was using relies on PackageManager? Would love some help on this as I'm not sure what else I can do. Thank you

Comment: Please update your package with the latest version permission_handler: ^10.0.2

Comment: thats the thing, im not using permission_handler

Comment: Okay, if you don't use this package you may clear your cache and then run your application

Comment: doesnt work still the same error